# Calling method of object property in mocked object results in NullPointerException

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have the following scenario:

```
public class MyObject {
    ObjectA a;

    public void method(){
        a.getObjectB.getSomething();
}
```

Now in my JUnit tests I'm mocking (using mockito) and injecting ObjectA, my problem is the getObjectB is staying null even after I tried injecting ObjectB through reflection. Any ideas how I can fix this?

The unit test is as follows:

```
@Mock ObjectA a

@Mock ObjectB b

MyObject c

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        c = new MyObject();
        MyObject.setObjectA(a);
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(c, "b", b);
        when(stepExecution.getObjectB().getSomething()).thenReturn("Stuff);
}

@Test
public void testSomething()
{
    c.myMethod() 
}
```

Comment: I even tried  when(a.getObjectB.getSomething()).thenReturn("Stuff"); with no luck

Comment: Can you post your test code?

Comment: you should post more complete code, including your unit test

Comment: you have to mock both ObjectA & ObjectB. when a.getObjectB return mockobjectB and when mockObjectB.getSomething return "stuff".

Comment: getObjectB() is what is returning null and getSomething() is what is throwing the exception

Comment: @kswaughs That solved my problem thanks :) Can you make an answer so I can accept it please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mock both the objects ObjectA & ObjectB and set their expectations as you required.

```
when(a.getObjectB()).thenReturn(b); 
when(b.getSomething()).thenReturn("Stuff");
```